# Goland git ignores directory while git sees it just fine

Tags: git, goland

I have an "ui" directory in my Go project, which is a Quasar project. For some reason, Goland's git will not detect changes in it - at all. If I run `git status` in terminal(the same as Goland uses), I see the changes just fine and can commit and amend them. But Goland Git UI will simply be blind to this entire directory and I just cannot figure out why. I though this might be because Goland has this, in my experience, stupid thing of change lists, where you can divide changes into groups and not commit them at once. But there is only one default list, so this is not it.

Comment: Could you please share the content of _Preferences/Settings | Version Control | Directory Mappings_?

Comment: @s0xzwasd the directory was listed there and it was red. i have removed it and the problem is gone. strange, i haven't seen this before. thanks! If you want some points, post an answer so I can accept it. Otherwise I will probably delete this question.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Make sure that your project root directory is displayed correctly under *Preferences/Settings | Version Control | Directory Mappings* (or has *<Project>* entry) and *VCS* has *Git* as an option.

[image]

Answer (score 0):

Make sure GIT plugin is enabled.

Should be under *Settings -> Plugins -> Installed -> Git*

[image]